# what is the meaning of "then...as now" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

what is the meaning of "then...as now" in this context?

> During these years of public mediumship, when the girls were all the
>   rage among those who had no conception of the religious significance
>   of this new revelation, and who concerned themselves with it purely in
>   the hope of worldly advantage, the sisters exposed themselves to the
>   enervating influences of promiscuous séances in a way which no earnest
>   Spiritualist could justify. **The dangers of such practices were not
>   then so clearly realized as now**, nor had it occurred to people that it
>   is unlikely that high spirits would descend to earth in order to
>   advise as to the state of railway stocks or the issue of love affairs.
>   The ignorance was universal, and there was no wise mentor at the elbow
>   of these poor pioneers to point the higher and the safer path. Worst
>   of all, their jaded energies were renewed by the offer of wine at a
>   time when one at least of them was hardly more than a child. It is
>   said that there was some family predisposition towards alcoholism, but
>   even without such a taint their whole procedure and mode of life were
>   rash to the last degree. Against their moral character there has never
>   been a breath of suspicion, but they had taken a road which leads to
>   degeneration of mind and character, though it was many years before
>   the more serious effects were manifest.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Answer (score 1):

*The dangers of such practices were not then so clearly realized as now*
means
**The dangers of such practices are more clearly realized now than they were then**

*it was many years before the more serious effects were manifest*
means
**the more serious effects were only manifest many years later**